# Parsing error with JSON request to moviedb

Tags: java, json

When I make requests to movieDb.org (most popular or most TopRated movies) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JsonObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JsonArray
    at Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

My code is:

```
import org.json.simple.DeserializationException;
import org.json.simple.JsonArray;
import org.json.simple.JsonObject;
import org.json.simple.Jsoner;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final String API_URL = "https://[site]/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=00dd64934f886ad5f0a1257af58fda25";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_URL);
            // GET PAGE CONTENT
            Scanner contentScan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while (contentScan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = contentScan.nextLine();
                buffer.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.json")) {
            fos.write(buffer.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String jsonResponse = buffer.toString();
        try {
            // PARSE JSON
            JsonArray movieResult = (JsonArray) Jsoner.deserialize(jsonResponse);

            for (int i = 0; i < movieResult.size(); i++) {
                // GET JSON OBJECT FROM ARRAY
                JsonObject movie = (JsonObject) movieResult.get(i);

                // GET DATA FROM OBJECT
                String object = movie.getString("object");
                int page = movie.getInteger("page");
                String poster_path = movie.getString("poster_path");
                boolean adult = movie.getBoolean("adult");
                String overview = movie.getString("overview");
                String release_date = movie.getString("realese_date");
                int id = movie.getInteger("id");
                String original_title = movie.getString("original_title");
                String original_lang = movie.getString("original_language");
                String title = movie.getString("tite");
                double pop = movie.getDouble("popularity");
                int vote = movie.getInteger("vote_count");
                boolean video = movie.getBoolean("video");
                // PRINT DATA
                System.out.printf(object +"   "+  page + "\n");
                System.out.printf("%s %s B: %6.3f S: %6.3f [Q:1]\n", poster_path, adult, overview, release_date, id, original_title, original_lang, title, pop, vote, video);
            }
        } catch (DeserializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight or indicate which line is line 47? Seems you have a data type inconsistency, you are casting a Jobject as a Jarray

Comment: JsonArray movieResult = (JsonArray) Jsoner.deserialize(jsonResponse);

Comment: What it is better to do, so that everything works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server JSON response is not a `JsonArray` but a `JsonObject` containing a `JsonArray`:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [{
        "poster_path": "\/9O7gLzmreU0nGkIB6K3BsJbzvNv.jpg",
        "adult": false,
        "overview": "Framed in the 1940s for the double murder of his wife and her lover, upstanding banker Andy Dufresne begins a new life at the Shawshank prison, where he puts his accounting skills to work for an amoral warden. During his long stretch in prison, Dufresne comes to be admired by the other inmates -- including an older prisoner named Red -- for his integrity and unquenchable sense of hope.",
        "release_date": "1994-09-23",
        "genre_ids": [18, 80],
        "id": 278,
        "original_title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "original_language": "en",
        "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "backdrop_path": "\/xBKGJQsAIeweesB79KC89FpBrVr.jpg",
        "popularity": 10.718322,
        "vote_count": 6557,
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 8.4
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

So you have to use `results` key before iterate over each movie data, something like (this is only the PARSE JSON part as others lines of code looks almost good):

```
// Parse server response to JsonObject
JsonObject movieResultWrapper = (JsonObject) Jsoner.deserialize(jsonResponse);

// Get JsonArray link to "results" key 
JsonArray movieResult = (JsonArray) movieResultWrapper.get("results");

// Iterate over your JsonArray and process data
for (int i = 0; i < movieResult.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject movie = (JsonObject) movieResult.get(i);

    // Be careful in your code your are trying to get "object" and "page" but these keys do not exist!
    // String object = movie.getString("object");
    // int page = movie.getInteger("page");

    // All others parsing look good
    String poster_path = movie.getString("poster_path");
    boolean adult = movie.getBoolean("adult");
    String overview = movie.getString("overview");
    String release_date = movie.getString("realese_date");
    int id = movie.getInteger("id");
    String original_title = movie.getString("original_title");
    String original_lang = movie.getString("original_language");
    String title = movie.getString("tite");
    double pop = movie.getDouble("popularity");
    int vote = movie.getInteger("vote_count");
    boolean video = movie.getBoolean("video");
    // PRINT DATA
    // System.out.printf(object +"   "+  page + "\n");
    System.out.printf("%s %s B: %6.3f S: %6.3f [Q:1]\n", poster_path, adult, overview, release_date, id, original_title, original_lang, title, pop, vote, video);
}
```

Comment: so i have to iterate for 20 times(for each movie) or i can use something else?

Comment: The `for-loop` is the iteration over each movie. BTW server response contains a `page` attribute so it surely means that a pagination is available on server side.

Comment: Thanks/ will look for solutions.